# Test class assumption failing after 2 years

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I have a test class that has been in production for nearly 2 years. It is mostly self contained including an XML string that is interpreted and then broken into the component parts and stored. Then we search, in various ways, for the items that are stored and compare the results against assumptions.

```
    Result = SkillsSoftCtrl.FindCourse(null, 'All', Root.id, false, false);
    System.assertEquals(4, Result.size());
```

Nothing has changed so I don't know why the test are just now failing. Also - the full sandbox has no issue.

Comment: If today was February 29th I'd guess it was a date logic bug. Both production and the sandbox are summer '15 right?

Comment: something may have changed in your prod environment after the most recent fullcopy sandbox refresh (permissions, custom settings, static resources, ....) you can rerun the test class in PROD w debug to gain insight

Comment: Yes. I added logging to the test class and the control class that it references. I cmmented out the assert and am trying to see what is different. Nothing thus far.

Comment: i may have misinterpreted your use case. presumably, the test class is already in PROD -- so, when you use DC in PROD, does the class fail (presumably YES). Does the debug log in PROD prove illuminating?  I trust the testclass is at V24+ and is not using `SeeAlldata=true` (a notorious source of deployment isssues)